# how to use regular expression to get value from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string text:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        h2 {
            color: #e2703b;
        }.newsimage{
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }.date{
            text-align:right;font-size:35px;
        }
    </style>
```

*Newlines and idents are added for clarity, real string does not have it*

How can I get value of `h2` color? In this case it should be - `#e2703b;` I don't know how to use regular expressions in this case.

**Update**
If I try this way:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(cssSettings, @"h2 {color: (#[\d|[a-f]]{6};)");
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    }
```

it doesn't work at all

Comment: The more correct expression: h2\s*{color:\s*(#[a-f\d]{6};)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if regex is the way to go, but you can extract the value by using this regex:

```
h2 \\{color: (#(\\d|[a-f]){6};)}
```

Getting the first Group from this will get you the value that belongs to the color of the h2.

**Edit**

This piece of code should get it:

```
String regex = "h2 \\{color: (#(\\d|[a-f]){6};)}";
String input = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;\" charset=\"utf-8\"><style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;}h2 {color: #e2703b;}.newsimage{margin-bottom:10px;}.date{text-align:right;font-size:35px;}</style>";
MatchCollection coll = Regex.Matches(input, regex);
String result = coll[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: I'm just still checking it in code, you can go here to see the result of the regex: http://www.rubular.com/r/3euPeCg1PK

Comment: Do you need to escape the curly braces?

Comment: the last curly braces is not necessary

Comment: true, doesn't harm either, anyway, I updated the regex and added the code I used to test

Comment: I used this to find a date in a string and worked but the value was in group 0 like this coll[0].Groups[0].Value;

Comment: how can we access the values from month and day (?<Month>\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s)(?<day>\d{1,2})

Answer (score 1):

As you have said there are **no tabs[\s] and line feeds[\n]** in the string.Hence the regular expression would be:

```
(?<=[.]*h2{color:)[#\w]*(?=[.]*)
```

Hence the code becomes,

```
Match match = Regex.Match(cssSettings, @"(?<=[.]*h2{color:)[#\w]*(?=[.]*)");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    string key = match.Value;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@"h2\s*{\s*color: (#.{6};)"
```

Comment: i think it gives "h2 { color: #e2703b;" as output

Comment: Have you tried with code in the question: `string key = match.Groups[1].Value;` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite robust wrt. optional spaces, line breaks and stuff. Also finds half-width color codes and does not jump into the next block if `h2` has no `color`.

```
h2\s*\{[^}]*color\s*:\s*?(#[a-f\d]{3}|#[a-f\d]{6})\b
```

Result in the first and only captured group.

[Try it!](http://regexr.com?313jb)